# Centos 7 syslog rate limiting strangeness

Tags: centos7, syslog, rsyslog

I'm seeing some confusing results of syslog rate limiting on Centos 7.

With this release it seems that rsyslogd is getting its input from journald. Which means that the first place syslog messages are rate limited is by journald.

In journald.conf I can adjust the rate limit with these two lines:

```
RateLimitInterval=60s
RateLimitBurst=100
```

Setting RateLimitInterval to 0 seems to properly disable it and no rate limit is in place.

What is really strange is that any other values work not quite like you expect. If I sit there trying to flood syslog with perhaps 1000 lines/minute, the above setting would seem to limit me to actually logging 100/minute. But what happens? I actually log 275 lines/minute.

If I change the RateLimitBurst value to 1000, instead of logging 1000/minute, I log about 2750.

No matter what I do, I get an actual log rate of about 2.75 times greater than expected.

It would seem that something in journald is maybe doing some incorrect time conversion.

This is easy to reproduce, 100% on any of the Centos 7.2 systems I am using.

After messages are limited by journald they are further limited by the imjournal setting in rsyslogd, but I don't think that is coming into play here.

Anyone else see this? It matters because I have an app that is a little noisy, spewing quite a few messages which are diverted to a specific file, and I need to adjust the limit to a higher value. But I want it to be done in a sensible way.